# What is our community's stand on Inviting non Muslim friends to join this community?

Tags: discussion

I am living in a non Muslim country and have several non Muslim friends/colleagues. During conversation there often comes a topic which I am not qualified to answer. Moreover I feel like there are some kind of questions(the controversial/sensitive type) they want to know the answer to but feel uncomfortable to ask.

Situation like this I believe could be resolved if I suggest the curious ones to join Islam StackExchange, since here they can have certain anonymity and distant themselves from people to ask all kind of questions even the sensitive ones and get better idea and possibly clear up any misinformation they might have from media or other source.

Since I am no expert on Islam nor on this community norms, I wanted to know how the community feels regarding inviting non Muslim people in this community? Since at least in my opening this could clear up many misinformation rest of the world have and might possibly open their eyes to Islam.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Inviting non-Muslims is absolutely fine. There is nothing in the [official policy](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) to the effect that this site is exclusive for Muslims only. What is stated is:

> Islam Stack Exchange is for experts in Islam, students of knowledge, and those interested in Islam on an academic level.